# Hair particle system messes up scene lighting

Tags: light, hair

When I add a hair particle system to my scene, almost all of the shadows disappear. I have experimented with multiple different systems and with linking/creating in the scene. I have attached a before/after of my scene.

[image]

[image: Before]

[image: After adding the rug with a hair particle system]

Comment: Possibly another setting you accidently checked? Have you baked the particle system?

Comment: The only setting I changed between the two renders was deselecting visible in render for the rug.Hair dynamics are disabled, so there is no cache to bake.

Comment: If the file size is not to big (because of the hair) could you please add it to your post?

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 I have added the .blend file for just the rug.

Comment: The file does not contain a particle system for the rug, as it was not saved into the file. Try this, and I'm only wildy guessing that this may fix your issue. However, I can't work with the file because of this.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Oh sorry, I uploaded the wrong file, I have uploaded the correct one now.